# Set focus on edit box after displaying message in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to set the focus on the edit box again after displaying message.

```pascal
portno := Edit.Text;
if (portno = '') then
begin
  MsgBox('Enter Port Number to proceed.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := False;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `TForm.ActiveControl` of the `WizardForm`:

```
WizardForm.ActiveControl := Edit;
```

This answer shows this in action:
[Port range validation for data input in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53917243/850848#53917471)